# Highlight every matched pattern while searching in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have `set incsearch` set in my .vimrc and it highlights **EVERY** matched pattern *only* when tapping enter. But is there any way to highlight all the matches **while** typing in the search?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That's what `:set incsearch` is about: showing the matches **while typing the pattern**:

[image]

Ensure that the `IncSearch` highlight group actually has distinctive visual features; it may have been cleared:

```
:hi IncSearch
```

Only the **next match** is highlighted here; this is to enable the features mentioned at `:help 'incsearch'`:

> CTRL-L can be used to add one character from after the current match
>   to the command line.  If 'ignorecase' and 'smartcase' are set and the
>   command line has no uppercase characters, the added character is
>   converted to lowercase.
>
> CTRL-R CTRL-W can be used to add the word at the end of the current
>   match, excluding the characters that were already typed.

If you want **all matches** highlighted, you have to either modify Vim's source code (and eventually post a patch), or re-implement search (using `getchar()` and `matchad()`) entirely in Vimscript. Both are not trivial, so I'd recommend to stick with the status quo.

Comment: I just modified the question; I am looking for a way to highlight **EVERY** match in the page while typing.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear. I've expanded my answer; unfortunately, this isn't easy, and you'll lose some nice functionality.

Comment: +1 Ingo's answer first. always informative and clear. and @JikkuJose you may want to reconsider your requirement. 1) it could be slow when the file is big, vim has to do match with whole buffer and hl them for your every single type. 2) it could be not so convenient, e.g. when you were typing a regex.

Comment: Hmm, anyway to trigger a <cr> after every character entered?

Comment: @Kent I doubt whether it will be that performance intensive as Sublime does this pretty well.

Comment: @Kent It could limit itself to search the part of the buffer currently displayed on screen, and wouldn't highlighting of what the regexp currently matches be really, really useful?