# Vim: Incsearch for replace queries

Tags: regex, vim

I noticed I could use regex functions with search in vim, and I could see hilights while I typed by [setting incsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899816/highlight-every-matched-pattern-while-searching-in-vim). But that didn't work for search and replace queries like this one:

`:%s/std::regex\s\([_a-zA-Z]*\)(/regex_t \1 = dregc(/gc`

That one surprised me when it actually worked.

Are there settings or plugins for vim that, like incsearch but better, will highlight your *replace* query as you type? Just highlighting the matches would be pretty neat, but putting the old and new strings next to eachother in different highlighting colors would be a godsend, because I might not be sure about the backreference.

Comment: "Though they were limited"? What feature(s) are you missing? The syntax is different but Vim supports most of the concepts of Perl regex.

Comment: Actually, now that I double checked it, the only thing the search function was missing was showing the backreference. I remember having problems with some brackets, but I'm not able to duplicate that now, so I'll remove that phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for [vim-over](https://github.com/osyo-manga/vim-over)?

This is a plugin that: (to clarify, let's say we're doing `:%s/foo/bar/g`.) i) highlights matches for substitutions in the buffer (`foo`) and optionally ii) previews what's after replacement (`bar`).

Comment: Bundle installed and tested. It even works for regular expressions! My only complaint is that I have to use `:OverCommandLine` instead of `:%s`, but I can just map that function to a key to save time.

Comment: Using the settings: `map <C-F> :OverCommandLine<CR>/`,
`map <C-R> :OverCommandLine<CR>%s/`, and `map r :redo<CR>` in my .vimrc, I can now use the kay-mappings that most editors use.

Answer (score 7):

Not a direct answer to your question, but traditionally in Vim you craft your search regex first, as in:

`/regex`

Then you hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to execute it. The settings `:set hlsearch` and `:set incsearch` make this easy to see visually. Then you can just do:

`:%s//replace`

With no search specified, `:%s` (**s**ubstitute acting on **`%`**, a shorctut meaning all lines in the file) will use the last search term you specified.

Going one step further, you could then do

`:%s/~/replace2`

Which replaces your last substitution (in this case, `replace1`) with `replace2`.

Unrelated, it may be useful for you to put this in your `.vimrc`:

`set gdefault`

Which will make all replaces global by default, so you don't need the `/g` flag after every `:%s` command.

Comment: It's true that this isn't a direct answer to my question, but I didn't know about `:%s/~/replace2` or `gdefault`, so it was helpful.