# Make vim highlight matched pattern in substitute command

Tags: regex, vim

When I use search in vim with `/` command, while typing in characters, I am able to see first occurrence of searched regular expression pattern via highlighting in text area of vim. However, while using `:s` command, I want to be able to see first occurrence highlighted as I type pattern for what-to-substitute block, but I see no highlighting, as I understand, it is because of command-mode, which is give no highlighting even for search via `/` in it.

For example, as I type `:s/foo/bar`, if there's any `fo` sequence in text, I want it to be highlighted after I typed in `:s/fo`, but it is not.

Does anybody knows any workaround for this? thx.

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448911/vim-incsearch-for-replace-queries/26451368#26451368).

Comment: @Yosh dear sir, you just saved my life, just what I was looking for!

Comment: In neovim, one can set the `inccommand` to show highlight and live preview of substitution. `set inccommand=nosplit`

Answer (score 13):

You can't: `:s` is a `:` command, not a search command, and highlighting can only be done on search commands.

But despair not!

`/foo` highlights stuff, then `:s//bar` replaces stuff using the last search string.

Comment: what if I wanted to capture parts of `foo`?

Comment: @MaxCoplan Sorry, but that's too vague, I don't understand what you're asking. Can you make a specific example?

Comment: As in using regex capture groups in `vim`.  So if I have a bunch of `h3` tags like `<h3>stuff</h3>`and I wanted to capture the inside of the tag and do something with `stuff`

Comment: @MaxCoplan Yes, you can do that, exactly as if you wrote the pattern in `:s` itself. For example, `/<h3>\zs.*\ze<\/h3>` followed by `:s//chuff/` does exactly the same thing as `:s/<h3>\zs.*\ze<\/h3>/chuff/`, and `/\(<h3>\).*\(<\/h3>\)` followed by `:s//\1chuff\2/` does exactly the same thing as `:s//\1chuff\2/`. However, [beware Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Ah, perfect!  Thank you

Comment: this seems to only replace instances on the same line, not across the whole document

Comment: @MaxCoplan Yes, just like `:s/foo/bar` in OP's example. If you want the whole document, you have to say so, using the range `1,$`, or `%` in short: `:%s/foo/bar`. It also only replaces once per line; if you want it to replace all occurrences in each line, use the `g` modifier: `:%s/foo/bar/g`. When you use the previous pattern, this would boil down to `:%s//bar/g`.